# Indexing problem in array

Tags: combinatorics

Given an array A=[a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 ... aN], I am looking for an algorithm that enables to find all potential combinations of subarrays of size at least 2 without changing the sequence of intervals (consecutive partitioning of the original array). The concatenation of all sub-arrays shall give the original array.

For example
A=[1 3 4 5 6], I am looking for an algorithm that will give the following answers:

(1 array combinations)
a1: [1 3 4 5 6]
(2 array combinations)
a2: [1 3] [4 5 6]
a3: [1 3 4] [5 6]

Another example A=[1 3 4 5 6 8]

(1 array combinations)
a1: [1 3 4 5 6 8]
(2 array combinations)
a2: [1 3] [4 5 6 8]
a3: [1 3 4] [5 6 8]
a4: [1 3 4 5] [6 8]
(3 array combinations)
a5: [1 3] [4 5] [6 8]

What the should be the state space size (complexity of the search algorithm)?

Comment: Nothing to do with this one. You can easily check this by considering the size of the state space for the examples I gave. Its not exponentially increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(n)$ be the number of partitions for an array of $n$ elements. My claim is that $F(1) = 0$, $F(2) = 1$, and$F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$ when $n > 2$. It is trivial to see that the values for $F(0)$ and $F(1)$ are correct so the tricky part is proving the recursive formula. To see that it is true note that the partitions of an array $[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]$ come in two different forms:

1. The cases where $[a_1, a_2]$ is part of the partition
2. The cases where $[a_1, a_2]$ is not part of the partition

You can get all of the partitions in case (1) by generating the partitions for the smaller array $[a_3, a_4, ..., a_n]$ and adding in $[a_1, a_2]$ for each partition. This means there are $F(n-2)$ partitions like this.

You can get all of partitions in case (2) by generating the partitions for the array with $a_1$ missing ($[a_2, a_3, ..., a_n]$) and then prepending $a_1$ to the sub-array containing $a_2$ of the partitions. This means we have $F(n-1)$ such partitions.

The total number of partitions would then be the sum of these two cases which is $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$. This is exactly the fibonacci sequence except shifted over (normally $F(1) = 1$) which has the closed solution:

$$ F(n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$

This means your complexity is in fact exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudocode for an algorithm which yields all such partitions:

- If $N<2$, yield nothing.
- For each $k$ in $\{2,3,\dots,N\}$:

  - Recursively yield $\{A(1),A(2),\dots,A(k)\}$, appended with each of the partitions of $\{A(k+1),\dots,A(N)\}$.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I get the idea but if possible can you formalize a little bit? Thank you